# checkbox checked is not working on extension chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

on extenstion install, the checkbox is checked, but the extension is not working, the extension start work after, user click on extension icon, I want the extesion start working without clicking the extension icon, beucose the checkbox is checked, somone know how to fix this?

popup.html

```
<div class="Av-AutoChangeButton">Player</div> 
<div class="onoffswitch" style="margin: 0 auto;">
<input type="checkbox" class="PlayerCheckBox onoffswitch-checkbox" id="AvVidPlayer" checked/>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="AvVidPlayer">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
</div>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if (window.location.href.match('chrome-extension://')) {
        load();
    }
});

$("body").on("change", ".PlayerCheckBox", function() {
    var status = "";
    $(".PlayerCheckBox").each(function() {
        status = status + ($(this).is(":checked")) + ",";
    });

    save_option(status);
});

function save_option(option) {
    var save = {};
    save[option] = null;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        option : option
    }, function() {
        console.log(option + "save");
    });
}

function load() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty("option")) {
            tab = obj.option.split(",");

            console.log(tab);
            var l = 0;
            $(".PlayerCheckBox").each(function() {
                $(".PlayerCheckBox:eq(" + l + ")").prop("checked", parseBoolean(tab[l]));
                l++;
            });
        } else {
        save_option("true,true,true,true,true,true");
        }
    });

}

function parseBoolean(str) {
    return /true/i.test(str);
}
```

backgrund.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(tab) {
   chrome.storage.sync.set({state: 'on'});
});
```

I want to run this script `redirect.js`

```
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty("option")){
            tab = obj.option.split(",");
        if(tab[0]!=='false'){
            AvStreamStart(tab);
            }
        }
    });
function AvStreamStart(tab) {
/* my script here
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you exactly mean by "extesion start working without clicking the extension icon". Which script do you want to run without clicking - popup or background? _FYI_: popup script _**should**_ only be run after click on extension icon.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have edit my question, so I want to run `redirect.js`

Comment: So just call it from background script

Comment: how! can you show me an example of how? Thanks again

Comment: If you can't use `import`, another solution is add `redirect.js` to manifest's "background" field or create background page with both scripts (`background` and `redirect`) included.

Comment: I tried with both scripts, but is not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is just copy-paste the code from `redirect.js` to `background.js`.

However if you want to modularize your code you may list these scripts under the "background" field of the manifest, as an array after "scripts" key.

`manifest.json`:

```
...
"background": {
    "scripts": [
         "redirect.js",
         "background.js"
    ]
}
...
```

Another way is register background script as an html page in the manifest with all needed JS scripts included in that html.

`manifest.json`:

```
...
"background": {
    "page": "background.html"
}
...
...
```

`background.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="redirect.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help